# Removing all pip packages installed at system level?

Tags: python, pip, uninstallation

When I started learning Python I didn't know about virtualenv and so installed all my stuff at system level.

I wanted to do a full clean out to prevent issues. However, creating the requirements.txt and then trying to run uninstall on it throws the following error and doesn't complete any uninstalling. Any ideas what might be wrong?

```
> Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/uninstall.py", line 76, in run
    requirement_set.uninstall(auto_confirm=options.yes)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 346, in uninstall
    req.uninstall(auto_confirm=auto_confirm)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 754, in uninstall
    paths_to_remove.remove(auto_confirm)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_uninstall.py", line 115, in remove
    renames(path, new_path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 267, in renames
    shutil.move(old, new)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.12_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 303, in move
    os.unlink(src)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/awscli-1.11.83.dist-info/DESCRIPTION.rst'
```

Comment: `OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied` is a great start here. Your `user` does not have permission to `unlink` some files. Perhaps, you forgot to invoke `sudo`?

Comment: i definitely called sudo as this was my first thought

Comment: This may be related to [this pip issue](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/3165). My guess is that it worked when you started the terminal because some of the dependencies were already uninstalled in the first pass. So when you started the terminal those changes took effect and the overall uninstallation went through smoothly.

Answer (score 1):

Not an amazing solution but i rebooted terminal and tried sudo again and it cooperated this time... i cant offer more than that im afrad